# how to change folder location based on requested filename with mod_rewrite?

Tags: html, apache, redirect, url-rewriting, robots.txt

lets say url is requesting robots.txt like

```
http://domain1.com/robots.txt
```

and i want this url to look into http://domain1.com/domain1/robots.txt but keep the above url

any idea how to this is correct way? redirecting like this for robots.txt is allowed?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any idea how to this is correct way? redirecting like this for robots.txt is allowed?

Yes, just add this to your `domain1.com` document root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase    /
RewriteRule    ^robots\.txt$    domain1/robots.txt  [L,NS]
```

This will do an internal redirect to the file that you want.  For more info see the Apache [rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).